# Wikipedia: What does $\int g(x, \xi) d \xi$ mean for $g \in L^1(\mathbb R^n)$, $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-transform, solution-verification

In the proof of the Fourier inversion theorem [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem#Proof) it says

> For $f,g \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, Fubini's theorem implies that
>   $$
> \int g(x, \xi) \hat{f}(\xi) d \xi 
> = \int \hat{g}(x,y) d(y) dy.
> $$

Denote by $c := (2 \pi)^{-\frac{n}{2}}$, then my calculation with Fubini (F) indeed yields
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g(x, \xi) \hat{f}(\xi) d \xi
& = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g(x, \xi) \cdot c  \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(y) e^{-i \langle y, \xi \rangle} d y d \xi 
\overset{\text{F}}{=} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(y) \cdot c \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g(x, \xi)  e^{-i \langle y, \xi \rangle} d \xi d y \\
& = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(y) \cdot c \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g(x, \xi)  e^{-i \langle \xi, y \rangle} d \xi d y 
= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(y) \hat{g}(x,y) dy,
\end{align}
but how is $g$ to be understood? As $x$ and $\xi$ are $\mathbb R^n$-values, and $g \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, what is $g(x, \xi)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like it can be written less confusingly like this.
\begin{align*}
\int_\mathbb{R}g(\xi)\hat{f}(\xi)d\xi &= \int_\mathbb{R}g(\xi)\int_\mathbb{R}f(x)e^{-2\pi i\langle x, \xi\rangle}dxd\xi\\
&= \int_\mathbb{R}f(x)\int_\mathbb{R}g(\xi)e^{-2\pi i\langle x, \xi\rangle}d\xi dx\\
&= \int_\mathbb{R}f(x)\hat{g}(x)dx.
\end{align*}
Fubini was used moving from the first line to the second.

Comment: Do you have any idea why they resorted to present it otherwise though? It doesn't seem to be used in the proof, too.

Comment: My guess is that they write $g(x,\xi)$ to mean "$g$ depends on $x$ and its Fourier transform depends on $\xi$."